# How can I print a custom message for unpublished nodes upon submission?

Tags: 8, rules

Structure > Content type > ContentX > Edit > Unchecked published.

Structure > People > Permission > Anonymous users have access to create node for Content Type "ContentX".

An anonymous user goes to the page ../node/add/geo and fill up the form and be able to save the unpublished node. However, the user goes not get any message stating that the node is saved. I like to display a message to the user that user is saved and it is pending approval.

Based on my research, I need Rules module.

Enabled the Rules module for D8.

In Rules module, I like to configure it to display a message to the user when the unpublished node is saved.

[image]

[image]

Here I am not sure what to enter:

[image]

How would I configure the settings in Rules module to display a message when a node from a specific content type is saved but not published?

Comment: clic on 'Switch to data selection' and drill until you find proper data, then in 'Acions section' post the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be using the current -dev version of Rules - that will make it much easier to do what you want.

Second, for the "Node is of type" condition, switch to the data selector for the first entry then select "node" from the data selector. This is the data object "node" that was created. For the content type, enter the machine id of the content type using the direct input mode (the default).